# Entity DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime-format, savechanges

I'm using entity data model in my server application written in C# (.NET Framework 4.6.1). I'm requesting data from a device (via Eneter.Messaging.Framework) where is a client application written also in C# but in Compact Framework(v3.9). Everything works good but when I'm try to send DateTime as string from client to server and save it to database I get a entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception error. This error doesn't occurs when I send `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` date but in other cases I'm getting error.

For example I try to send `string date = (new DateTime(2000,11,11,11,11,11)).ToString()` and I get error `DbUpdateException`  when I want to save received object to database using `db.SaveChanges()`. Obviously I parse received value `DateTime.Parse(iten.Date)`.

I tried to send others date formats, but it didnt't work.

Comment: You should have the details of the exception in the InnerException property of the Exception, can you share that too? Also, what database system are you using and what's the structure of the table including the data type of the date field?

Comment: DateTime.Parse(iten.Date) gives you valid date?

Comment: Yeah, parsing gives me valid date. I'm using sql server 2014, column is `datetime` type. Table has another 30 columns. I have checked that just the date causes problem.